# how compute $a_n$ respect to b?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Assume sequence ${a_n}$ ,$a_n\in \Bbb R\,$ is defined by :

$$a_0=0\quad a_1=b\quad a_{n+1}=a_n\sqrt{1+a^2_{n-1}} +\sqrt{1+a^2_n} \quad,\;n\ge1$$ how calculate $a_n$ respect to b? thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any suggestions about $a_n$?

Comment: i compute it recursively .at first compute $a_n$ $a_{n}=a_{n-1}\sqrt{1+a^2_{n-2}} +\sqrt{1+a^2_n-1}$ and replace it in above but it doesn't help me

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo May I ask in what context did this problem appear to you?

Comment: @Git-gud: this question is from Iran contest math

Comment: Could you compute a few more terms of the sequence just to see what kind of pattern emerges?

Answer (score 1):

One may assume $b\geq0$. Put $a_n(b):=a_n$, given that $a_1=b$. Then obviously $a_n(b)\geq a_n(0)=:a_n$.

Now $a_0=a_1=0$, $a_2=1$, and $a_3=1+\sqrt{2}>1$. The sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$ is obviously increasing. It follows that for $n\geq 3$ we have 
$$a_{n+1}\geq a_n\ \sqrt{1+a_{n-1}^2}\geq a_n\ \sqrt{1+a_2^2} =a_n \sqrt{2}\ ,$$
which implies that the $a_n$ grow exponentially fast to $\infty$ with $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Actually, it's much worse than that.  By your own logic, $a_{n+1}\geq a_na_{n-1}$, so $\ln(a_{n+1})\geq \ln(a_n)+\ln(a_{n-1})$; thus there's some $k$ such that $\ln(a_n)\geq F_{n-k}\approx \phi^{n-k}$ (where $F_n$ are the Fibonacci numbers) and $a_n$ grows at least as fast as $\exp(\phi^{n-k})$ for some $k$ - i.e., doubly-exponentially.